# Problem With baking normal map with _Multires_

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I was trying to figure out how I was able to create my own characters normalmap , I reshaped it and hit the bake button with  >> (bake from multires ON and Baketype to normalmap ) Now I Got a Problem that one of the faces can not be baked nicely can anyone tell me the reason?[image] [image][image][image]I my self Believe the problem is for my topologizing . But I dont know how to fix it

Comment: Ops It Was For the Bad Topologizing :/